# Remote database connectivity in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, synchronization

I have a windows tablet application which store some data from the users. Now i need to send this data to a server via Internet. What all options are there for me to try?? I think syncng the server and client database wont do good since multiple tablets are getting connected to the server.

Comment: That's not something you should handle at the database level. Create a web service that receives the data and then store it in the server database, along with information where it came from (the server database schema is likely to be different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I think syncng the server and client database wont do good since multiple tablets are getting connected to the server.`
Why do you think that? How do you think web servers work? Databases can easily handle multiple connections.

You can either directly connect to the db server, if it supports remote connections, or you can create a webservice and communicate with db via that. Either way, be sure to set the permissions right, otherwise you might have a serious security problem.

// edit to address concerns in the comments

If you want to use a direct connection, you connect to a database exactly the same way as if it was on the same machine. How do you connect to that CE db?? You just need to alter the connection string, but everything else stays the same.

If you want to use a webservice for parsing and communicating with the database, the things get a bit more complicated, but it's still fairly simple. Search the google (or SO) how to use a webservice and how to create one. There are plenty of examples and tutorials out there. It's impossible to cover it all in here I'm afraid.

Comment: So can you please tell me where to start with.. I am having the application built in WPF using c# and SQL CE database. So now my database have 17 tables that stores data for a single session or user. I now need to have it send to the server so that i could do some calculations there and then notify the result to the user.. (please note i dont even know how to make a connection to the server from the application)..

Comment: @user1765361, updated. I'm afraid I can't answer your question in more detail, unless I'd start writing a book... ;)

Comment: thanks for your help... can you please help me to find some good tutorials or so.. i have googled before asking here but i am confused where to begin from..

Comment: @user1765361, for instance this looks fine: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/WebServices/276_How_to_consume_a_Web_Service_in_WPF_Application.aspx and this http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/